# Save Network Dialog Missing "Cancel" and "Save" Options

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, android-unity-plugin

I am building an android plugin for Unity that saves wifi networks to the device. I am using the [ACTION_WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I7b0.png) intent and it seems to be working fine.

I've exported the library as an aar file, imported it into my unity project, and added a wrapper that calls my method from the plugin.

The plugin works fine on my android 12 phone and on an emulator running android 11. I can interact with the dialog box and it successfully connects to and saves the network.

However, on my tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab A7 Lite, running android 11) the dialog shows up, but the options are not there:
[image]

If I turn the display off and on again, the options show up:
[image]

After refreshing the display like this the plugin works as expected, but I would like the options to show up without having to do this.

Is this a device-specific bug, or am I doing something wrong in my plugin? As I said above, it works on my android 12 phone and an emulator running 11